# How to redirect empty url to a specific page

Tags: htaccess, redirects

I have an event website and I want visitors to www.example.org to be redirected to www.example.org/todays-info

"todays-info" is an entry, and I have "Enable strict URL'S" set to No so that I can leave out the template group.

I'm using Cloudflare, and want to cache the html of www.example.org/todays-info to reduce the load on the server, so I want everyone sent to that specific page on visiting so they hit the cached page rather than the homepage.

I'm using the standard htaccess from Ellis Lab to remove index.php and when I try this redirect I just get into a loop

```
Redirect 301 /  http://www.example.org/todays-info
```

I'm guessing that the rewrite to remove index.php is part of the problem.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My friend... I'm afraid your syntax is incorrect. Place this rule **after** your index.php rewrites (at the end of the standard EllisLab htaccess file):

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/?$ http://www.example.org/todays-info
```

This is the magic you seek. The second parameter of a RedirectMatch is a **regular expression**.

Comment: Thanks, I always get confused about Redirect, Rewrite & RedirectMatch and when to use which.

Comment: Oh yeah, there's always like ten different ways to accomplish stuff like this with htaccess. This is the best option unless you need to specifically avoid a 301 fire. Glad you got it resolved!